# Change textbox's css class when ASP.NET Validation fails

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, validation, webforms

How can I execute some javascript when a Required Field Validator attached to a textbox fails client-side validation?  What I am trying to do is change the css class of the textbox, to make the textbox's border show red.

I am using webforms and I do have the jquery library available to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is quick and dirty thing (but it works!)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" 
                                 ControlToValidate="txtOne" Text="SomeText 1" />
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwo" runat="server" />
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" runat="server" 
                                 ControlToValidate="txtTwo" Text="SomeText 2" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnOne" runat="server" OnClientClick="return BtnClick();" 
                                         Text="Click" CausesValidation="true" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BtnClick() {
            //var v1 = "#<%= rfv.ClientID %>";
            //var v2 = "#<%= rfv2.ClientID %>";
            var val = Page_ClientValidate();
            if (!val) {
                var i = 0;
                for (; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                    if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                        $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate)
                         .css("background-color", "red");
                    }
                }
            }            
            return val;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think your v1 and v2 variables are unused :P

Comment: yep, but this is quick and **dirty** :D. just commented them.

Comment: maybe dirty, but I haven't found a better solution !! :P

Comment: What is the reason to write the `var i = 0` statement outside of the for loop?

Comment: Because the only variable scope delimiter in js is the function. So declaring it inside the for declaration is misleading.

Comment: As a sidenote, if the control has more than one validator, you will need to implement a control logic to avoid style override on multiple validations.

Answer (score 21):

You could use the following script:

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        if (typeof ValidatorUpdateDisplay != 'undefined') {
            var originalValidatorUpdateDisplay = ValidatorUpdateDisplay;

            ValidatorUpdateDisplay = function (val) {
                if (!val.isvalid) {
                    $("#" + val.controltovalidate).css("border", "2px solid red");
                }

                originalValidatorUpdateDisplay(val);
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

This code decorates the original ValidatorUpdateDisplay function responsible for updating the display of your validators, updating the controltovalidate as necessary.

Hope this helps,

Comment: To enable easier custom styling, you can do: $("#" + val.controltovalidate).toggleClass('error', !val.isvalid);

Comment: +1 saved me some Google time here, thank you gsimoes and @GrimaceofDespair

Answer (score 2):

I think you would want to use a [Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx) and then use the ClientValidationFunction... Unless it helpfully adds a css class upon fail.

Comment: Important notice: this won't work for trying to check whether a field is empty or not; the CustomValidator isn't triggered if the field to check is empty.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I spend a few hours on it and since then I have been using some custom js magic to accomplish this.

In fact is quite simple and in the way that ASP.NET validation works. The basic idea is add a css class to attach a javascript event on each control you want quick visual feedback.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    /* Color ASP NET validation */
    function validateColor(obj) {
         var valid = obj.Validators;
         var isValid = true;

         for (i in valid)
              if (!valid[i].isvalid)
                  isValid = false;

         if (!isValid)
             $(obj).addClass('novalid', 1000);
         else
             $(obj).removeClass('novalid', 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".validateColor").change(function() {validateColor(this);});
    });
</script>
```

For instance, that will be the code to add on an ASP.Net textbox control. Yes, you can put as many as you want and it will only imply add a CssClass value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBxEmail" runat="server" CssClass="validateColor" />
```

What it does is trigger ASP.Net client side validation when there is a change on working control and apply a css class if it's not valid. So to customize visualization you can rely on css.

```
.novalid {
    border: 2px solid #D00000;
}
```

It's not perfect but almost :) and at least **your code won't suffer from extra stuff**. And 
the best, works with all kind of Asp.Net validators, event custom ones.

I haven't seen something like this googling so I wan't to share my trick with you. Hope it helps.

*extra stuff on server side*:

After some time using this I also add this ".novalid" css class from code behind when need some particular validation on things that perhaps could be only checked on server side this way:

```
Page.Validate();
    if (!requiredFecha.IsValid || !CustomValidateFecha.IsValid)
        txtFecha.CssClass = "validateColor novalid";
    else
        txtFecha.CssClass = "validateColor";
```

Comment: What if user doesnt input anything and posts the page. This code won't validate on submit...

Comment: @HasanG&#252;rsoy I wrote this long time ago but the idea was mainly to add some behavior on standard ASP.net controls. I guess you can add some onClick behavior over any submit elements to trigger calling the function as well.

Comment: Hmm yes, thank you. But I guess it will cause the same bug as I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477219/asp-net-issue-with-chaining-required-field-and-regular-expression-validators-f

Comment: @HasanGürsoy sure as you then will need a custom validator probably

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

Advantages over other solutions:

- Integrates seamlessly with ASP.NET - NO changes required to code. Just call the method on page load in a master page.
- Automatically changes the CSS class when the text box or control changes

Disadvantages:

- Uses some internal features of ASP.NET JavaScript code
- Tested only on ASP.NET 4.0

HOW TO USE:

- Requires JQuery
- Call the "Validation_Load" function when the page loads
- Declare a "control_validation_error" CSS class

  ```
  function Validation_Load() {
  if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "object") {
      return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
      var val = Page_Validators[i];
      var control = $("#" + val.controltovalidate);
      if (control.length > 0) {
          var tagName = control[0].tagName;
          if (tagName != "INPUT" && tagName != "TEXTAREA" && tagName != "SELECT") {
              // Validate sub controls
          }
          else {
              // Validate the control
              control.change(function () {
                  var validators = this.Validators;
                  if (typeof (validators) == "object") {
                      var isvalid = true;
                      for (var k = 0; k < validators.length; k++) {
                          var val = validators[k];
                          if (val.isvalid != true) {
                              isvalid = false;
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                      if (isvalid == true) {
                          // Clear the error
                          $(this).removeClass("control_validation_error");
                      }
                      else {
                          // Show the error
                          $(this).addClass("control_validation_error");
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, just iterate through the page controls as follows: (needs a using System.Collections.Generic reference)

```
const string CSSCLASS = " error";    

protected static Control FindControlIterative(Control root, string id)
{
   Control ctl = root;
   LinkedList<Control> ctls = new LinkedList<Control>();
   while ( ctl != null )
   {
     if ( ctl.ID == id ) return ctl;
     foreach ( Control child in ctl.Controls )
     {
       if ( child.ID == id ) return child;
       if ( child.HasControls() ) ctls.AddLast(child);
     }
     ctl = ctls.First.Value;
     ctls.Remove(ctl);
   }
   return null;
}



protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Add css classes to invalid items
  if ( Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsValid )
  {
    foreach ( BaseValidator item in Page.Validators )
    {
       var ctrltoVal = (WebControl)FindControlIterative(Page.Form, item.ControlToValidate);
       if ( !item.IsValid ) ctrltoVal.CssClass += " N";
       else ctrltoVal.CssClass.Replace(" N", "");
    }
  }
}
```

Should work for most cases, and means you dont have to update it when you add validators. Ive added this code into a cstom Pageclass so it runs site wide on any page I have added validators to.

Comment: Its very inefficient to iterate through every control on a page, I don't think you should do this.