# Issue with chaining Required Field and Regular Expression validators for Textbox controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm trying to implement a form validation with ASP.net and I have tried every solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301508/change-textboxs-css-class-when-asp-net-validation-fails) but the best one was on [aspsnippets.com](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Change-Background-and-Border-Color-of-Invalid-Controls-when-Validation-fails-in-ASP.Net.aspx) so far.

My code is like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tTitle" runat="server" onblur="WebForm_OnBlur()"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tTitle"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="tEMail" runat="server" onblur="WebForm_OnBlur()"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tEMail"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tEMail"
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"/>

<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false)
    {
        for (var i in Page_Validators) {
            try {
                var control =
                document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    control.className = "error";
                } else {
                    control.className = "";
                }
            } catch (e) { }
        } return false;
    } return true;
}
function WebForm_OnBlur() {
    for (var i in Page_Validators) {
        try {
            var control =
            document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
            if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                control.className = "error";
            } else {
                control.className = "";
            }
        } catch (e) { }
    } return false;
}
</script>
```

The problem is the e-mail field only validates for the regular expression. If I change the order of the validators, it only validates for required expression.

The possible problem is that the code loops through all the validators but does not compare the ones that reference the same control at once. This causes only the last validator condition to be applied on the control.

Comment: What about creating a server side custom validator. I dont really do a lot of web form development anymore. But I have done some server based custom validator back in 2010 I guess. Here is an useful to that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.90).aspx good luck

Comment: What is the value you are entering into the `tEmail` field during your testing?

Comment: Yes creating a custom control will solve the issue @qamar.

Comment: Value depends on validators order of tEmail field.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - do you not get all validation errors shown or does it not trigger all validators? Also as a side note - be sure you're validating server side as well and not just client side. Client side validation can be bypassed easily.

Comment: I need a solution for styling inputs like in MVC forms.

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Comment: Where are you calling the function `WebForm_OnSubmit()`

Comment: "In order to change the colors of invalid controls we will override the ASP.Net WebForm_OnSubmit which is an inbuilt ASP.Net JavaScript method." see the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The possible problem is that the code loops through all the validators but does not compare the ones that reference the same control at once. This causes only the last validator condition to be applied on the control.

Yes, this is indeed the problem. To fix it, you can do the following:

In the `WebForm_OnBlur` function, loop through the validators associated with the control that lost focus (rather than all the validators on the page), and clear the `className` property only if all the validators are valid:

```
function WebForm_OnBlur(control) {
    for (var i = 0; i < control.Validators.length; i++) {
        if (!control.Validators[i].isvalid) {
            control.className = "error";
            return;
        }
    }
    control.className = "";
}
```

In the `onblur` attribute of the `TextBox` controls, pass `this` as the argument to `WebForm_OnBlur`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tTitle" runat="server" onblur="WebForm_OnBlur(this)"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="tEMail" runat="server" onblur="WebForm_OnBlur(this)"/>
```

In the `WebForm_OnSubmit` function, call `WebForm_OnBlur` for each control that has associated validators:

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
    if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) === "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() === false) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            var control = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
            if (Page_Validators[i] === control.Validators[0]) // minor optimization
                WebForm_OnBlur(control);
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @MichaelLiu,  You can make your own validators that inherit from the `CustomValidator` class and alter the rendering of the validators to make them a little easier to work with.

For example:

#### Validators.cs

---

Take notice of how we add a property of `CssControlErrorClass`.  We will use this when applying a class with the invalid input in question.

We also set other properties so you don't have to set them everytime, `ClientValidationFunction` and `ValidateEmptyText`.

```
public class RequiredFieldValidator : CustomValidator
{
    public string CssControlErrorClass { get; set; }

    public RequiredFieldValidator()
    {
        ClientValidationFunction = "validators.required";
        ValidateEmptyText = true;
    }

    public string InitialValue
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["InitialValue"];
            return ((o == null) ? String.Empty : (string)o);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["InitialValue"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //Have to add attributes BEFORE the beginning tag is written to the stream
        writer.AddAttribute("data-errorClass", CssControlErrorClass);
        writer.AddAttribute("data-for", GetControlRenderID(ControlToValidate));

        base.Render(writer);
    }



    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
    {
        //Default implementation of the RequiredFieldValidation validator
        string controlValue = GetControlValidationValue(ControlToValidate);

        if (controlValue == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var result = (!controlValue.Trim().Equals(InitialValue.Trim()));

        //Check to see if validation failed, if it did, add the class to the control to validate
        if (!result)
        {
            var control = (WebControl) NamingContainer.FindControl(ControlToValidate);

            //Didn't look into it too much, but the validators fire twice for some reason
            if(!control.CssClass.Contains(CssControlErrorClass)) control.CssClass += " " + CssControlErrorClass;
        }

        return result;
    }
}


public class RegularExpressionValidator : CustomValidator
{
    public string CssControlErrorClass { get; set; }

    public string ValidationExpression
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["ValidationExpression"];
            return ((o == null) ? String.Empty : (string)o);
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                Regex.IsMatch(String.Empty, value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new HttpException(string.Format("{0} - {1}", "Validator_bad_regex", value), e);
            }
            ViewState["ValidationExpression"] = value;
        }
    }

    public RegularExpressionValidator()
    {
        ClientValidationFunction = "validators.regex";
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //Have to add attributes BEFORE the beginning tag is written to the stream
        writer.AddAttribute("data-errorClass", CssControlErrorClass);
        writer.AddAttribute("data-regex", ValidationExpression);
        writer.AddAttribute("data-for", GetControlRenderID(ControlToValidate));

        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
    {
        //Default implementation of the RegularExpressionFieldvalidator
        string controlValue = GetControlValidationValue(ControlToValidate);
        if (controlValue == null || controlValue.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        try
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(controlValue, ValidationExpression);
            var result = (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == controlValue.Length);

            //Check to see if validation failed, if it did, add the class to the control to validate
            if (!result)
            {
                var control = (WebControl) NamingContainer.FindControl(ControlToValidate);

                //Didn't look into it too much, but the validators fire twice for some reason
                if (!control.CssClass.Contains(CssControlErrorClass)) control.CssClass += " " + CssControlErrorClass;
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Validators.js

---

Since in the previous classes we pre-defined the javascript functions, we can add a simple script like so:

```
var v = window.validators = window.validators || {
    errorControlAttributeName: "data-for",
    errorClassAttributeName: "data-errorClass",
    regexAttributeName: "data-regex",

    required: function(src, args) {
        var controlId = src.getAttribute(v.errorControlAttributeName),
            errorClass = src.getAttribute(v.errorClassAttributeName),
            input = document.getElementById(controlId);

        var isValid = (args.Value !== "");

        v._toggleInputErrorState(input, errorClass, isValid);

        args.IsValid = isValid;
        return;
    },

    regex: function(src, args) {
        var controlId = src.getAttribute(v.errorControlAttributeName),
            errorClass = src.getAttribute(v.errorClassAttributeName),
            regexString = src.getAttribute(v.regexAttributeName),
            input = document.getElementById(controlId),
            regex = new RegExp(regexString);

        var isValid = regex.test(args.Value);

        v._toggleInputErrorState(input, errorClass, isValid);
        args.IsValid = isValid;
        return;
    },    

    /************* Helper functions ***********/

    _toggleInputErrorState: function (inputEl, errorClass, isValid) {
        if (!isValid) {
            if (!v._hasClass(inputEl, errorClass)) {
                inputEl.className += " " + errorClass;
            }
        } else {
            if (v._hasClass(inputEl, errorClass)) {
                //Not the most performant, but is sure is easiest
                inputEl.className = inputEl.className.replace(" " + errorClass, "");
            }
        }
    },

    _hasClass: function(el, className) {
        return el.className.indexOf(className) != -1 ? true : false;
    },
}
```

Very simple validation library that you can easily extend with things you are actually interesting in.

#### Default.aspx

---

After than you can put the controls into your page:

```
<Validators:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssControlErrorClass="input-validation-error" ControlToValidate="Test" ErrorMessage="REQUIRED BRO!"></Validators:RequiredFieldValidator>
<Validators:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]" CssControlErrorClass="input-validation-error" ControlToValidate="Test" ErrorMessage="REQUIRED RegEx BRO!"></Validators:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Is this the best way?  Probably not, (these two use the default implementation that is given by Microsoft) there are way smarter people out there than I and I don't work with WebForms much.  The biggest benefit I see is that you get some reusable code, using a familiar syntax, that will eventually contain all your validation needs versus messing around with js everytime to get the validation "rules" how you want them.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved by replacing the code snippet below. To correct we must loop through all the validators for a control, then we should decide whether it has to marked with the error class. After this, your code will work as expected.

Replace the loop

```
 for (var i in Page_Validators) {
    try {
        var control =
        document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
            control.className = "error";
        } else {
            control.className = "";
        }
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

with the below code

```
 for (var j in Page_Validators) {
        try {
            var control =
                        document.getElementById(Page_Validators[j].controltovalidate);
            var IsError = false;
            for (var i in control.Validators) {

                if (!control.Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    IsError = true;
                }
            }

            if (IsError)
                control.className = "error";
            else
                control.className = "";
        } catch (e) { }
    }
```

I just ran it and this is working excellently :) Try this solution!

Answer (score -1):

you can try Page_ClientValidate() in javascript instead of looping across validator.
I believe this will validate all the validators on the page.
It also takes in parameter which "Validation group name" if you want to validate specific controls bound by particular validation group.

Comment: And what about adding css class to the invalid controls?