# Show red border on textbox on error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to show an error by changing the color of the border of a text box. I have found a lot of posts on how to do it, but I have never done anything with 'Validators' so I am confused where to start, or where to put the code.

**Similar posts:**

[Post One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196859/change-text-box-color-using-required-field-validator-no-extender-controls-pleas)

[Post Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301508/change-textboxs-css-class-when-asp-net-validation-fails)

My main question(s) are, where do I put the JS code? And secondly, how do I call the code?

**Current Code**

```
 If TicketNumber.Text = String.Empty = True Then
        NotificationLabel.Text = "Ticket Number must be filled out"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: you should add tags for asp or Js or whatever to attract the attention of the right eyes

Comment: @Plutonix Good advise, thanks!

Comment: Found [Similar Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559196/how-to-make-the-textbox-border-become-red-when-a-validation-happens-to-it-in-asp) and its working perfectly using client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RequiredFieldValidator` could do it with some tricks explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237890/how-do-i-highlight-a-textbox-border-red-when-it-is-required), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196859/change-text-box-color-using-required-field-validator-no-extender-controls-pleas). Another way is to use a `CustomValidator` like the following.

**aspx mark-up**

```asp
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbText" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvCustom" ErrorMessage="Ticket Number must be filled out" 
    ControlToValidate="tbText" runat="server" OnServerValidate="ValidateInput"
     ClientValidationFunction="ValidateInput" ValidateEmptyText="True" />
<asp:Button Text="My Button" runat="server" />
```

**Javascript**

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateInput(sender, args) {
        if (args.Value == '') {
            args.IsValid = false;
            document.getElementById('<%= tbText.ClientID %>').style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

**Code Behind (C#)**

```c#
protected void ValidateInput(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.Value))
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        tbText.Style["border-color"] = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }   
}
```