# How to make the TextBox border become red when a validation happens to it in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, validation

[This what i want to do.click to view photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H0uL.jpg)

I tired many options but all did not work. like overriding JS methods and custom methods. i will be thankful for a clear, working response.

```
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style2">&emsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name"
        CssClass="style3" AssociatedControlID="TextBoxName"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"
            CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3"
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field required"
            ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" Text="Required"
            ForeColor="Red" Font-
            Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" Font-
            Overline="False" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="Red">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a script I use for this purpose.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //set the interval for checking the validators
    setInterval(function () { colorBorders() }, 100);

    function colorBorders() {
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) !== 'undefined') {

            //loop all the validators
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                var validator = Page_Validators[i];
                var control = document.getElementById(validator.controltovalidate);

                //check if the control actually exists
                if (control != null) {

                    //if the validator is not valid color the border red, if it is valid return to default color
                    //elseif with rgb color is nessecary for preventing chrome dropdown blinking
                    if (!validator.isvalid) {
                        control.style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
                    } else if (control.style.borderColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
                        control.style.borderColor = '#000000';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: should i rename the Page_Validators with the Id of the validation

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything. If you place this on a page it will work for all validators.

Comment: i tried it . thanks a lot man i was trying to do this from 24 hours i really hope you hear good news soon . can you tell me where you got it so i can get more knowledge

Comment: Probably (parts of) from here on SO I think. I've been using it for a while now. And made some modifications myself.