# asp.net validator add class to input if validation is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to add css class to validated input if value isnt valid ? Im using asp.net validators.

Maybe there is javascript event on taht validators which I can use ?

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to do that with normal ASP.NET Validators as it don't provide a rich client-side library.

If you don't need to change your current validators types. you can use the HighlightCssClass property of **ValidatorCallout** control from ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit.

You can check a demo here:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use the build-in `CustomValidator` like so:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="vldCustomValidator" EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="Your error message goes here"
    ClientValidationFunction="JavascriptValidationFunction" 
    ControlToValidate="txbControl"
    runat="server" />
```

**Usage scenario**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could override the Default ASP.NET validation script and inject your own script to add the classes to parent div.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857696/618044

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in this way. you add custom HTML tags and CSS class.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RrequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtCustomerName" ForeColor="Red"
    Display="Dynamic">
    <span class="bubbletooltip">Please Enter Name Here</span>
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```